# Reading a line by scanf but it reads twice

Tags: c, loops, scanf

This is the code

```
int
read_data(void){
    char type;
    double x_val,y_val,noise_val;   
    while (scanf("%c %lf %lf %lf",&type,&x_val,&y_val,&noise_val)==4){
        printf("%c %lf %lf %lf",type,x_val,y_val,noise_val);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the input is

```
N 501.0 7501.0 80.0
N 1001.0 5001.0 90.0
N 3501.0 7501.0 130.0
N 5001.0 2001.0 85.0
```

when I enter after compiling as `test < testing.txt` it only prints the first line.

However if i remove the while loop and keep adding more scanfs and prints this is the output.

```
N 501.000000 7501.000000 80.000000

 501.000000 7501.000000 80.000000
N 1001.000000 5001.000000 90.000000

 1001.000000 5001.000000 90.000000
N 3501.000000 7501.000000 130.000000

 3501.000000 7501.000000 130.000000
N 5001.000000 2001.000000 85.000000

 5001.000000 2001.000000 85.000000
```

what is going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `scanf` call doesn't read the *newline* after the first line, it will still be in the input buffer, so the next time you call `scanf` the `"%c"` format will read that newline, and then attempt to read the character `N` as a floating point number, which will fail and the loop will exit.

A simple solution is to use `fgets` to read the lines, and then use `sscanf` to parse the lines you have read.